# Cannot figure out the error

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I keep getting errors with this query? and I cannot figure out how to write it properly.

> Incorrect syntax near >

```
CONVERT (
                       VARCHAR (5000)
                     , SUBSTRING (
                                     Message
                                   , CHARINDEX ('^14=', Message) + 4
                                   , CHARINDEX ('^', Message, CHARINDEX ('^14=', Message) + 4)
                                     - CHARINDEX ('^14=', Message) - 4,SUBSTRING(

                  CHARINDEX ('^14=', Message) > 0,
             CHARINDEX ('^', Message, CHARINDEX ('^14=', Message) + 4)>0)) AS [ErrorMessage]
```

Comment: What errors are you getting?  What DB?  More information please...

Comment: Please provide input table structure, sample input data, expected output and what is the error.

Comment: Count your parentheses. You are missing one at the very end to close your `Convert()` function. Please next time share the error message and the rest of the query.

Comment: Incoorect syntax near >

Comment: Debugging is part of programmers job!!!!  Have you even tried to `SELECT SUBSTRING(...)` to check whether that whole statement run or not???

Comment: This is odd though `Substring(CHARINDEX ('^14=', Message) > 0, ....`) What do you anticipate `CHARINDEX ('^14=', Message) > 0` is going to return. I would suspect it will return a boolean (true/false)(1/0). How would you substring a boolean? I think you need to break down this complex logic and try each little bit out by itself to see what you are getting before trying to stitch this monster together and watching it fail.

Comment: Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). "The title is the first thing potential answerers will see, and if your title isn't interesting, they won't read the rest. So make it count" Consider [edit]ing it to at least be the error message you are getting.

Answer (score 2):

It's unclear what you are trying to do, but you aren't using `SUBSTRING()` correctly. As [the docs state](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/substring-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), this function is `substring(expression, start, length)`. Here is your attempt (scroll right to read the comments):

```
CONVERT (VARCHAR (5000)
        ,SUBSTRING(Message,                                                                                                 --expression
                  CHARINDEX ('^14=', Message) + 4,                                                                          --start
                  CHARINDEX ('^', Message, CHARINDEX ('^14=', Message) + 4) - CHARINDEX ('^14=', Message) - 4               --length, needs a ) here to finish the SUBSTRING
            ,SUBSTRING(CHARINDEX ('^14=', Message) > 0, CHARINDEX ('^', Message, CHARINDEX ('^14=', Message) + 4)>0)    --what is this? Starting a new column? Some part of the length argument of the previous substring?
        ) AS [ErrorMessage]                                                                                                 --closing the COMVERT
```

You'll need to explain what you are attempting to do for further help. You may have an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) on your hands. However the **core** issues with your attempt are:

- You are missing a closing parentheses on the first `SUBSTRING()` call
- You have too many arguments in your `CONVERT()` function